# $.post variable as array with values?

Tags: jquery, post, arrays

sending some data via post but want to send an array to but keep getting errors?

excludes is the array i'm trying to send.

```
        $.post("/youradmin_v2/scripts/php/process.php", { 
            funcName:'searchContent',
            table:'content', 
            fields:'title,contentID', 
            keyword:$(this).val(), 
            tag:'option',
            excludes: ['contentType'=>'client','contentType'=>'mainsetion']                 
            }, 
            function(data){
            $("#filterContentMenu").html(data);
        });
```

I can't seem to find the correct way to format the array for posting?

or to clarify what i want is to turn this into a php array like

```
$excludes=array('fieldA'=>'client','feildB'=>'mainsetion')
```

to be used like

```
foreach($excludes as $value) {
        $toExclude .=" AND ".$value['name']."!='".$value['value']."' ".$value;
    }
```

Comment: *sigh* Please, please, please when you get error messages, *add that error message to your post*.

Comment: Question title should probably read "$.post variable...", as "$post variable..." is likely to be misinterpreted in this case.

Comment: [SQL injection alert](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)!

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be using PHP-style notation to specify the array keys.
Try

```
excludes: {'contentType':['client','mainsetion']}
```

Comment: You need to use curly braces for that, not square brackets. In JS, brackets are for arrays, not objects. Also note, you'll probably overwrite it with the second one; you might want it to be more along the lines of `excludes: {contentType: ['client', 'mainsetion']}`.

Comment: Why don't you edit your answer to make JS syntactically valid?

Comment: ++ short and sweet and to the point. may not be enough for OP to chew though. cheers.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $.post("/youradmin_v2/scripts/php/process.php", { 
         funcName:'searchContent',
         table:'content', 
         fields:'title,contentID', 
         keyword:'blah', 
         tag:'option',
         excludes: {contentType:'client',anotherContentType:'mainsetion'}              
        }, 
        function(data){
        $("#filterContentMenu").html(data);
    });
```

Comment: ok this array stops the error;
    {contentType:'client',anotherContentType:'mainsetion'} - thanks!

but its not getting picked up the way i expected by the php file.

basically i was trying to create a string for an sql query.
    ie "AND contentType!='client' AND contentType!='mainsection'"

but what i'm getting is
    AND c!='c' AND m!='m'
using php 
    foreach($excludes as $value) {
 $toExclude .="AND ".$value['name']."!='".$value['value']."' ";
    }

do you think what i'm doing is possible?! many thanks! Dan

Comment: examine the post - it's "excludes[contentType]" etc... also you cannot use the key name "contentType" twice. I think you can also do something like this "excludes: {contentType:['client','section']}".. just do a print_r($_POST) in your php to find out what it comes through as.

Comment: thanks vinhboy - i think i'm giving up on this method then. I'll just use a string via jquery which i wasn't to keen on doing due to security concerns.

so;
excludes:"AND contentType!='client' AND contentType!='mainsection'"

thanks for your responses!

Comment: oh.. i am sad you wont be using it :(...

excludes: {contentType:['client','section']}

becomes

$_POST['excludes']['contentType'] which is an array, so you can use in_array.

anywho, goodluck